# unable to run java class from command prompt refering to a jar in classpath

Tags: java

I am trying execute a java class which accesses a method in a jar file.My package structure is com.xmlpost.XmlPostInit.java and it resides under the directory:

```
  D:\Workspace\Test\bin
```

I am using the command below. Note, `cs.jar` contains the class com.xmlpost.XmlPostInit

```
D:\Workspace\Test\bin>java -classpath D:\FatWire\JSK\7.6.0\App_Server\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\cs\WEB-INF\lib\cs.jar com.xmlpost.XmlPostInit
```

.. which gives me following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xmlpost/XmlPostInit
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xmlpost.XmlPostInit
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.xmlpost.XmlPostInit.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your bin directory to the classpath too, as the JVM needs to look inside it to find your class. As you are running inside it, you can refer localy it with ".":

```
D:\Workspace\Test\bin>java -classpath .;D:\FatWire\JSK\7.6.0\App_Server\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\cs\WEB-INF\lib\cs.jar com.xmlpost.XmlPostInit
```

Comment: Tomas is right depending on whether you expect to get the class from cs.jar or from "D:\Workspace\Test\bin".  Your post isn't clear as to where com.xmlpost.XmlPostInit *should* be found.

Comment: @jowierun The question starts with "I am trying execute a java class [...] and it resides under the directory: [...]". It seems quite clear to me.

Comment: @user1228745 then, please, consider accepting the answer, so your question gets flagged as answered.